# What are good data on the Human Metabolic Model and where can I get them?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, metabolism, database, systems-biology

Trying to get a good SBML representation of the Human Metabolic Model for use in Flux Balance Analysis and drug targetting (i.e. gene knockout) simulations.

What are good sources for these data?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no one model officially known as "the Human Metabolic Model", but the Recon 2 model, described as a "consensus" model and the most comprehensive to date in *Thiele et al. 2013, A community-driven global reconstruction of human metabolism* (http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v31/n5/full/nbt.2488.html) is available at http://humanmetabolism.org/?page_id=75

Tissue-specific models are also available. See for example  *Wang et al.:  Reconstruction of genome-scale metabolic models for 126 human tissues using mCADRE. BMC Systems Biology 2012, 6:153:*

Comment: Interesting.  Yep, I have found Recon 2, but I am also having trouble matching the drug therapies against it (I assume I should do that through figuring out which genes are knocked out by each therapy and trying to match them with the model).  Tissue specific models sound interesting.  Thanks!